# My own Logging Handler for GAE/J (using appengine.api.log?)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

I need to write my own logging handler on GAE/J.  I have Android code that I'm trying to adapt such that it can be shared between GAE/J and Android.  The GAE code I'm trying to write would allow the log statements in my existing code to work on GAE.

The docs say that I can just print to system.out and system.err, and it works, but badly.  My logging shows up in the log viewer with too much extraneous text:

> 2013-03-08 19:37:11.355 [s~satethbreft22/1.365820955097965155].: [my_log_msg]

So, I started looking at [the GAE log API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/log/package-summary).  This looked hopeful initially: I can construct an AppLogLine and set the log records for a RequestLogs object.

However, there is no way to get the RequestLogs instance for the current request - the docs say so [explicitly here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Environment):

> Note: Currently, App Engine doesn't support the use of the request ID to directly look up the related logs.

I guess I could invent a new requestID and add log lines to that, but it is starting to look like this is just not meant to be?

Has anyone used this API to create their own log records, or otherwise managed to do their own logging to the log console.

Also, where can I find the source for GAE's java.util.logging?  Is this public?  I would like to see how that works if I can.

If what I'm trying to do is impossible then I will need to consider other options, e.g. writing my log output to a FusionTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just layering my logging code on top of GAE's java.util.logging.  This feels non-optimal since it increases the complexity and overhead of my logging, but I guess this is what any 3rd logging framework for GAE must do (unless it is OK with the extra cruft that gets added when you just print to stdout).

Here is the crux of my code:

```
public int println(int priority, String msg) {
    Throwable t = new Throwable();
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = t.getStackTrace();

    // Optional: translate from Android log levels to GAE log levels.
    final Level[] levels = { Level.FINEST, Level.FINER, Level.FINE, Level.CONFIG,Level.INFO, Level.WARNING, Level.SEVERE, Level.SEVERE };
    Level level = levels[priority];

    LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(level, msg);
    if (stackTrace.length > 2) { // should always be true
        lr.setSourceClassName(stackTrace[2].getClassName());
        lr.setSourceMethodName(stackTrace[2].getMethodName());
    }
    log.log(lr);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I use a stack depth of 2, but that # will depend on the 'depth' of your logging code.

I hope that Google will eventually support getting the current com.google.appengine.api.log.RequestLogs instance and inserting our own AppLogLine instances into it.  (The API's are actually there to do that, but they explicitly don't support it, as above.)